# Implement a common function in multiple Razor views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-views

In a View, I have a Razor code like

```
@Code

    Dim x As String = "MyTest"

End Code
```

However, how can I share that code with other Views without copy/paste it in all the Views?

Comment: By creating a partial View and including it in all pages ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a partial view, and then use the following code to render the partial view on your other pages:

```
@Html.RenderPartial("Path to partial view")
```

You can also pass a model to a strongly-typed partial view by including a second parameter:

```
@Html.RenderPartial("Path to partial view", myModel)
```